# Relationship between laravel models does not work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models: one for users and one for clients. A user is a customer

User has a 'codigocli' field and client has a 'codigo' field

The relationships between my models are like this:

```
//User model
public function cliente()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Cliente::class, 'codigo', 'codigocli');
}


//Cliente model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'codigocli', 'codigo');
}
```

My database is fine (I think) client has the 'codigo' field and users has the 'codigocli' field. So what am I doing wrong? When I want to query my home.blade.php with dd(auth()->user()-cliente()) I don't get anything, although it shows me the parent object fine.

Comment: `auth()->user()-cliente` or `auth()->user()-cliente()->first()`. If you leave it with just `()`, it's a Builder instance. You need to actually execute the query (either manually via `cliente()->first()`, or automatically via `->client` without the `()`)

Comment: @TimLewis I thought I had already tried it. I am new at this. Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries! Just make sure to read over the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties; this usage "gotcha" is detailed there 

Answer (score 0):

H
You have an OneToOne relationship here so try this if you don't change id name:

```
//User model
public function cliente()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Cliente::class, 'codigocli');
}
//Cliente model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'codigocli');
}
```

if you change id name:

```
//User model
public function cliente()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Cliente::class, 'codigocli','local_id_name' );
}
//Cliente model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'codigocli', 'local_id_name');
}
```